# How to create MongoDB docker image with my local database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Dockerizing my node application with MongoDB database.

I am unable to attached my MongoDB database on docker container. The docker image was created but with the newly created database it was not included the my local database into the Docker container.

What I have tried..

- Added volumes in docker-compose.yml file

```
  services:  
    database:   
      image: mongo:latest   
      restart: always   
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydatabase   ports:27017:27017   
      volumes:
        - ./mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
        - ./logs:/var/log/mongodb/
        - ./database:/var/lib/mongodb   
      command: mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

- Created the **etc/mongo.conf** file as well to assign dbpath in mongo container.
- Here add code of mongo.conf file.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb/dump
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

- Build this docker container with `docker-compose up --build` command.
- The image of my node-application and MongoDB was created and my node application was connected successfully with this image. but it was unable to find the mydatabase on created docker container image.

Any help will be appreciated.....

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Mongo's datadir is `/data/db`, you should use that instead of `/var/lib/mongodb`.

For more details, read https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo, section `Where to Store Data`.

Comment: Hi @snahor, Thanks for the reply. I have added that path because i have added mongo.conf file and add it to docker container which will update the default path from /data/db to /var/lib/mongodb.